# Tailwind one off arbitrary colors not working when written as variable

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Tailwind states that the following is possible when it comes to arbitrary colors we don't want to pollute the tailwind config with:

```
bg-[#e73d3dFF]
```

Now in the code, when writting said color like this, **it works**:

```
bg-[#e73d3dFF]
```

Here is the part that is baffling me, when written using any form of compilation (I'll show all examples), it **does not work**. The string is printed out onto the HTML correctly, but  the color isn't rendered.

**Example 1**

```
`bg-[${navItem.bg.hex}]`
```

**Example 2**

```
const classStyle = `bg-[${navItem.bg.hex}]`;
classNames({[classStyle]: true});
```

**Example 3:**

```
'bg-[' + {navItem.bg.hex} + ']';
```

**All** the examples above result in the HTML being printed correctly, so we do see:

```
<li class="bg-[#e73d3dFF]">
```

But, here's the kicker, the color isn't shown, the rules aren't applied, it's like the color rule wasn't created by Tailwind.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use template literal strings to build tailwind classes.
They warn about that in their docs, too: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names